# xml soap code that works in c#projects in visual studio but not in Python

Tags: c#, python, xml, soap

I understand that c# and Python is two different languages however I think the xml soap code should be roughly similar but yet I can't see to get it to work. The url that works in c# just ends up fetching me the webpage codes, I am using POST and want to input authentication and an input to retrieve information in the server. How do I go about doing it

I have tried various urls, various requests formats however I am not very familiar with how python and soap interact so all I could do was search online and adapt existing code, but they all seem to either give out an error when connecting(i think this is a url issue though) or retrieve the codes of the webpage itself.

```
 import requests 
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

    url= "http://website/websiteAPI.asmx?op=GetInformation" headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/soap+xml' 'charset=utf-8' 
    'SOAPAction' "http://website/websiteApi/GetInformation"}
    body = """

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   
     <soap:Body>
        <GetAssetListByType 
             xmlns="http://website/websiteApi/GetInformation">
          <user>test</user>
          <pass>456</pass>
          <RanCode>ver</RanCode>
        </GetAssetListByType>   </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>"""

    response = requests.post(url, data=body,headers=headers) 
print (response.content) 
print (response.status_code)
```

I expected to log in and be able to retrieve output from the server, however I received an error of 500/404/301 or codes of the webpage instead.

Comment: Why do you  `from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET`?

Comment: The http has headers and the default headers in c# are probably different from the xml soap and python.  To find root cause of issue you need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the working code and non working code.  To fix make the non work http headers look exactly like the working http headers.

Answer (score 0):

alright somehow I got it working with this code, I will be very honest in saying that I have no clue how it actually worked though.

```
import requests
request = u"""

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://website/websiteApi">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <theAPI>

         <user></pass>

         <pass></pass>
      </theAPI>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

headers = {"Host": "172.31.99.16",
           "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
           "Content-Length": "length"}

response = requests.post(url="http://website/websiteAPI.asmx?",
                         headers = headers,
                         data = encoded_request,
                         verify=False)
print (response.text)
print (response.status_code)
```

This works as a .py code for a soap xml request